# Adding cors to MEAN Singlepoint Application, for Swagger-ui

Tags: node.js, express, cors, swagger, swagger-ui

Im running a NodeJS server which is serving the UI with the builded Angular /dist folder.

In the UI I include the swagger-ui, which is loading an swagger.json, the *.json is describing a REST interface and within the swagger-ui you should be able to test REST Interfaces.

https://swagger.io/swagger-ui/

Project structure

[image]

In the server.js I added a fixed rout to the /dist path where the index.html is stored, also there are express routes to the rest Interfaces which my server is offering. to load the swagger.json Documentation files

server.js

```
// Get dependencies
const dotEnv      = require('dotenv').config();
const express     = require('express');
const path        = require('path');
const http        = require('http');
const bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
var mongoose      = require('mongoose');
const cors        = require('cors');
// Get our API routes
const api         = require('./server/routes/api');
const swaggerAPI  = require('./server/routes/swaggerAPI');
const app         = express();


var connectionUrl = typeof process.env.CONNECTION_URL  !== 'undefined' ?  process.env.CONNECTION_URL  : 'mongodb://db:27017/docdb';
console.log("Connection URL: " + connectionUrl);
mongoose.connect(connectionUrl);

// Parsers for POST data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Set our api routes
app.use('/api', api);
app.use('/swagger-api', swaggerAPI);

app.use('/client', express.static('client'));

app.use(cors());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST");
    if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
        res.status(204).send();
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
});

// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
const server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`));
```

Everthing works fine I can load the swagger.json with my REST interfaces, persist them in a MongoDB and show them in the Angular UI.
But when I want to test REST interfaces from the swagger-ui i get an error in console:

```
 Failed to load http://localhost:8888/****/Y7CTQW5PTSEG1MMPN: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

But when I debug the Request in Chrome, I can see the loaded data in the Network tab.

Why is the console showing the cors error, while loading the data and not showing it in the ui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Site A tries to fetch content from Site B, Site B can send an Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header to tell the browser that the content of this page is accessible to certain origins. (An origin is a domain, plus a scheme and port number.) By default, Site B's pages are not accessible to any other origin; using the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header opens a door for cross-origin access by specific requesting origins.

For each resource/page that Site B wants to make accessible to Site A, Site B should serve its pages with the response header:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteA.com
Modern browsers will not block cross-domain requests outright. If Site A requests a page from Site B, the browser will actually fetch the requested page on the network level and check if the response headers list Site A as a permitted requester domain. If Site B has not indicated that Site A is allowed to access this page, the browser will trigger the XMLHttpRequest's error event and deny the response data to the requesting JavaScript code.

Supposing that Site A wants to send a PUT request for /somePage, with a non-simple Content-Type value of application/json, the browser would first send a preflight request:

```
OPTIONS /somePage HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://siteA.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type
```

Note that Access-Control-Request-Method and Access-Control-Request-Headers are added by the browser automatically; you do not need to add them. This OPTIONS preflight gets the successful response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteA.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

When sending the actual request (after preflight is done), the behavior is identical to how a simple request is handled. In other words, a non-simple request whose preflight is successful is treated the same as a simple request (i.e., the server must still send Access-Control-Allow-Origin again for the actual response).

The browsers sends the actual request:

```
PUT /somePage HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://siteA.com
Content-Type: application/json
```

{ "myRequestContent": "JSON is so great" }
And the server sends back an Access-Control-Allow-Origin, just as it would for a simple request:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteA.com
See Understanding XMLHttpRequest over CORS for a little more information about non-simple requests.
Please check this links as well to solve and fix your problem.

[Cors content tutorial](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

[Using cors](http://restlet.com/company/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/)

[fixing cors](http://restlet.com/company/blog/2016/09/27/how-to-fix-cors-problems/)

Comment: Thanks Neha, I solved it by adding @CrossOrigin(origins = "*") to my spring Boot application which was my "Site B" in this case

Comment: All the CORS links seem to be outdated and the target pages may have moved.